# Difference in display:grid rendering between firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to create a master-detail view by rendering 2 CSS tables (display:table) side-by-side. To split the view, I'm using CSS Grid.

Master panel will usually have between 1-10 rows. However, detail content has > 50-60 rows.

I created a codepen: https://codepen.io/rahuldj/pen/ExYPpGm

It renders correctly in chrome. However, in firefox, the table with fewer rows stretches up to the same height as other (longer) table.

I tried explicitly specifying height for rows etc., but all that seems to get ignored in firefox when the parent is a grid.

Does anyone know of any fix for this?

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="th">
      <div>Column 1</div>
      <div>Column 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="th">
      <div>Column 1</div>
      <div>Column 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:0.3fr 0.7fr;
  grid-column-gap:30px;
}

.table{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

.th {
  display:table-row;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.th > div{
  display:table-cell;
}

.row{
  display:table-row;
}

.row > div{
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Min-height doesn't work on table elements in firefox, and that includes td. The reason is that a table cell will always stretch if necessary, so height actually is the equivalent of min-height for a table cell. And table-cell makes your element behave like td, so it makes sense that the same counts here. so try giving your table a height so that it extends automatically this code worked for me at firefox too !
add height:55px(some minimum height);
to the .table
Hope this helps

```css
.grid{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:0.3fr 0.7fr;
  grid-column-gap:30px;
}

.table{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  height:55px;
  background-color:lightgreen;
}

.th {
  display:table-row;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.th > div{
  display:table-cell;
  height: 31px;
}

.row{
  display:table-row;
}

.row > div{
  display: table-cell;
  height:31px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="th">
      <div>Column 1</div>
      <div>Column 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="th">
      <div>Column 1</div>
      <div>Column 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div>Data 1</div>
      <div>Data 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your approach does work. However, the number items in both tables is dynamic. So it isn't possible for me to pre-define the height in CSS.

It would be ideal if there was some way to get the same behavior as chrome in firefox (without hard-coding height in some form.)

Comment: This is suitable for dynamic too. I'll edit with more number of rows. Here the height works like min-height hence that will work dynamically too. @RJ